# Are there any related hooks for data fetching?

Tags: react-hooks

Are there any related hooks for data fetching? like fetch / ajax?

Support data fetch api.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should explore react-query.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [react-query](https://tanstack.com/query/v3/).
Compared to fetching data in useEffect hooks, you don't need to make method  from scrach to fetch data and loading variant.

And if you use in open api in your project, [orval](https://orval.dev/guides/react-query) is the best proctice to use react-query.
Because it also create fetchign react-query method automatically.